# The right way to make Q object, which filter all entries in Django QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

Now I use just `Q(id=0)`, and that depends on DB. Or maybe `Q(pk__isnull=True)` is better? It is useful for concatenation Q objects with using of `|` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a special method in Django QuerySet.
`Model.objects.none()` always returns empty queryset and is more clear for understanding.

Answer (score 3):

`Q(pk__isnull=True)` is better, because `PRIMARY KEY` cannot contain `NULL` values. There is possibility of that some instance could have `id=0`.

Answer (score 1):

The query optimizer handles `Q(pk__in=[])` better than `Q(pk__isnull=True)`. For example:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(pk__in=[]) # doesn't hit the DB
Model.objects.none() # doesn't hit the db
Model.objects.filter(Q(pk__isnull=True)) # hits the DB
```

If even works with complex queries and tilde negation:

```
Model.objects.filter( (Q(pk__in=[]) & Q(foo="bar")) | Q(hello="world") )
# simplifies condition to 'WHERE "hello" = world'

Model.objects.filter( ~(~Q(pk__in=[]) & Q(foo="bar")) | Q(hello="world") )
# simplifies condition to 'WHERE (NOT ("foo" = bar) OR "hello" = world)'
```