# Use a queryset to display two filtered data in django?

Tags: django

I have a table `Documents` and it has a field named `type` and the type has two data's namely - `type1 & type2`

Now my requirements is - i have a bootstrap tabs `type1 & type2`, and i need to display data accordingly on the template

Which is efficient way to do this ?

```
Using two variables

data = Documents.objects.filter(id=pk)
type1 = data.filter(type="type1")
type2 = data.filter(type="type2")

and then pass it to context 
context = { "type1":type1,"type2":type2 }
```

Is there any other best way to do this ?

Comment: May be this could help (https://stackoverflow.com/q/31160994/9572929)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they really have to be different querysets since they are different sets of data to be rendered. Also assuming `id` is your primary key (which looks like it is), note that the usage of `Documents.objects.filter(id=pk).filter(type=...)` would just consider that 1 object with that pk, you might want to change it to `Documents.objects.filter(type=...)`. Then you can make it a bit more dynamic by listing the possible types and then passing the filtered data to the template where the key is the type.

```
doc_types = ("type1", "type2")
context = {
    doc_type: Documents.objects.filter(type=doc_type)
    for doc_type in doc_types
}
```